# centos primary/secondary nameserver setup

Tags: centos, domain

I would like to know how to setup my (ve) server to host my website.

The (ve) server will have centos 5.5 installed with a LAMP stack.

I am specifically looking for a way to setup the domain/fqdn to point my registrar (http://co.za/) to my server IP. For example: www.mydomain.co.za takes me to my website.

What do I need to install/configure to get the above up and running?

Comment: Which registrar are you using?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I have no experience with co.za, but the first step is to set up the nameservers correctly for (ve). There should be an FAQ on the Mediatemple site to do this.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have a lot to learn. Still looking for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options for setting up DNS. I've listed them in order starting from the easiest and most common solution:

1. Configure DNS through your Registrar:

   Unless you are trying to install, configure, and maintain your own DNS servers, this is not a configuration that you make on the server. Most likely, you want to create an A (ipv4) record on your registrars administrative panel that tells their Nameservers the IP of your server. Registrars almost universally provide this service.
2. Configure DNS through your hosting provider:

   As has been mentioned hosts such as Linode provide DNS services. With these services you have to tell your registrar the nameservers for your host such as (ns1.linode.com). Subsequently, you will have to configure your domain through your hosts interface (web, api, etc.). (Im not sure that MediaTemple provides this service.)
3. Host your own DNS servers (not recommended):

   If you are truly trying to host your own DNS servers, you will have to tell your registrar about your authoritative nameservers for your domain and choose a DNS server such as BIND or MaraDNS to install on those hosts. This requires much more work (and some glue record magic as how can ns1.example.com resolve if it doesn't know who to ask about example.com).

*NOTE*: Your question is vague enough to suggest you don't know which option you need. So, choose one and I will be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

It's a very basic question. There are many howtos, particularly at wiki.centos.org.

Shortly, you need to configure named (or some other nsd) and to delegate a domain name to your server with nsd.

Comment: looks like we're getting somewhere, r u referring to this:http://library.linode.com/dns-guides/nsd-authoritative-dns-debian-6-squeeze, I'll mark as answer when successfully implemented. Thank you @Evgeniy

Comment: Start with Bind. http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=dns http://linuxgravity.com/configuring-bind9-domain-name-server-on-centos-or-red-hat

Comment: People don't tend to run their own DNS services these days. https://www.cloudflare.com provides this and many other services.